# Insert data in mongoDB database from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Context: Want to insert data in mongoDB database from node.js

Problem Statement: I am trying to insert data in the mongoDB database but thrown an error. Cant find it.

Present Output: Reference error

Attach Code:

**filter.js**

```
    var server = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');
    filter = express(),

    io = require('socket.io'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/filter_CheckBoxSchema', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else{
        console.log('Connected to mongodb!');
    }
});


    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);

    var filter_CheckBoxSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    type: Boolean,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
    });

    var Filter = mongoose.model('Store', filter_CheckBoxSchema);

    fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    } 

    new Filter({
        name: request.body.name,
        type: request.body.gender,

    }).save(function(err, doc){
        if(err) 
        {
            throw err;
        }
        else
        response.send('Successfully inserted!!!');
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Please enter your details</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <h3>Please enter your details</h3>
    <p>Please register below!!!</p>

    <form action="filter.js" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="Name" />
    <br /><p></p>
    Gender:
    <br /> 
    <input type="radio" name="gender"/> Male
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender"/> Female
    <p></p>
    Interest: (Check all that apply)
    <p>
    </p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="breakfast"/> Breakfast
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Lunch"/> Lunch
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Evening Snacks"/> Evening Snacks
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Dinner"/> Dinner
    <br />
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register!!!" />
    </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

**Output:**

```
C:\node\people discovery app>node filter.js
Connected to mongodb!

C:\node\people discovery app\filter.js:152
                name: request.body.name,
                      ^
ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at C:\node\people discovery app\filter.js:152:9
    at fs.js:271:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error says: `request` is not defined in the scope where you call `new Filter()`

Comment: can u tell me where to change

Comment: Change everything. A bit more reading on nodejs and callbacks is required here. Node programming is asynchronous and your programming style here is expecting each line to complete before the next is called, but that is not how this works. You are better off looking at [express](http://expressjs.com/) rather than implementing on such a low level. There are plenty of examples out there and also within questions on this site. Search and read, then ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you don't completely grasp the asynchronous nature of javascript. Variables passed to a function only exist in that function's scope. See this commented code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/filter_CheckBoxSchema', function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  } else{
    console.log('Connected to mongodb!');
  }
});

//Lets read our html file only once, at the very beginning when we first start our nodejs process
fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {

  //Now in here there are two variables which are accessible, `err` and `html`

  if (err) {
    throw err; 
  } 

  //Create our schema before starting server
  var filter_CheckBoxSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    type: Boolean,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  });

  //And now the model as well
  var Filter = mongoose.model('Store', filter_CheckBoxSchema);

  //Now lets start our server
  http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    //The code here is called whenever a new http request is sent to the server
    //There are two variables accessible here, one is `request` which contains
    //data about the original request, while `response` is an object with methods
    //allowing you to respond

    //Here we check what kind of method the browser is using, if its POSTing
    //data then we create a filter from the body
    if (request.method == "POST") {
      new Filter({
        name: request.body.name,
        type: request.body.gender,

      }).save(function(err, doc){
        if(err) 
        {
          throw err;
        }
        else {
          response.send('Successfully inserted!!!');
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      //This must have been a GET request, lets just send `html` instead
      response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
      response.write(html);  
      response.end();
    }
  }).listen(8000);        
});
```